Emby Server on TrueNAS Unable to Access Media in SMB Share Subdirectories
I’m currently facing an issue with my Emby media server (version 4.8.5.0) running on a TrueNAS Scale server. The problem is that Emby is unable to access or list media files if they are stored in subdirectories within an SMB share. However, if the media files are placed directly in the root of the SMB share, Emby can read and register them without any issues.
Additional context:

The same SMB share is accessible via Cyberduck and macOS Finder, and both can read and write to the subfolders without any problems.
The SMB share permissions appear to be configured correctly since other applications can access subdirectories.

I’m trying to determine if this is a known issue with Emby on TrueNAS or if there might be some configuration or permission detail that I am missing.
Questions:

Has anyone experienced similar issues with Emby on TrueNAS when accessing files in SMB share subdirectories?
Are there any known bugs related to this problem in Emby version 4.8.5.0?
What steps would you recommend for debugging this issue to find the root cause?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
